# Vespa - Proton: Custom bucketing & Query

Tags: vespa

References:

id scheme

```
Format: id:<namespace>:<document-type>:<key/value-pairs>:<user-specified>

http://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/content/buckets.html
http://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/content/idealstate.html
```

its possible to structure data in user defined bucketing logic by using 32 LSB in document-id format (n / g selections).

however, the query logic isn't very clear on how to route queries to a specific bucket range based on a decision taken in advance.

e.g., it is possible to split data into a time range (start-time/end-time) if i can define n (a number) compressing the range. all documents tagged such will end up in same bucket (that will follow its course of split on number of documents / size as configured).

however, how do i write a search query on data indexed in such manner?
is it possible to indicate the processor to choose a specific bucket, or range of buckets (in case distribution algorithm might have moved buckets)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can choose one bucket in a query by specifying the `streaming.groupname` query property.

Either in the http request by adding

```
&streaming.groupname=[group]
```

or in a Searcher by

```
query.properties().set("streaming.groupname","[group]").
```

If you want multiple buckets, use the parameter `streaming.selection` instead, which accepts any *document selection* expression: http://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/reference/document-select-language.html

To specify e.g two buckets, use set `streaming.selection` (in the HTTP request or a Searcher) to

```
id.group=="[group1]" and id.group=="[group2]"
```

See http://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/streaming-search.html

Note that streaming search should only be used when each query only need to search one or a few buckets. It avoids building reverse indexes, which is cheaper in that special case (only).

Comment: As one can reason, the streaming mode is quite costly and does not support stemming.

with a custom bucketing criteria while indexing very large dataset (> 10 billion documents), employing key-value pairs seems a good idea.
however, doing so forces me to use streaming search and the size of data i want to operate on will not go well with high cost.

any suggestions to index in a manner capable of having custom buckets (colocating the documents) and derive best performance and least size?

Comment: more specifically, if i won't go by key-value colocation scheme, how do i optimize query/search to target an exhaustive set that i can potentially define while indexing itself?

e.g. all video-ads purchased in a time-range (which is a known and growing set on an ad-server).

if this data is let loose into open bucketing scheme, what would be least costly lookup keeping 0 visibility-delay in mind.

Comment: Streaming search avoids reverse indexes, which means sense when you only ever search a small chunk of the total data in each query, and those chunks can be predetermined (typically used for personal data).

Comment: More discussion about your use case in https://github.com/vespa-engine/vespa/issues/3709#issuecomment-335912442

Answer (score 0):

The &streaming.* parameters is described here http://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/reference/search-api-reference.html#streaming.groupname

This only applies to document types which are configured with mode=streaming, for default mode which is index you cannot control the query routing http://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/reference/services-content.html#document